# missing `]' error when grouping conditions in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am trying to execute a logic as:

Pick The next Friday's date. If today is Friday, pick today's date. And, if current time is after 3pm, make it 9am. Else, use the current time.

The code I am using is:

```
CURR_DAY="$(date '+%A')"
NOW="$(date '+%H')"
CURR_HOUR="09"
if [ "$CURR_DAY" = "Friday" && "$NOW" < "15" ]; then
   CURR_TIME=$( date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
elif [ "$CURR_DAY" = "Friday" && "$NOW" > "14" ]; then
   CURR_TIME=$( date '+%Y%m%d')$CURR_HOUR$( date '+%M%S')
elif [ "$CURR_DAY" != "Friday" && "$NOW" > "14" ]; then
   CURR_TIME=$(date -d next-friday '+%Y%m%d')$CURR_HOUR$( date '+%M%S')
else
   CURR_TIME=$(date -d next-friday '+%Y%m%d')$( date '+%H%M%S')
fi
echo $CURR_TIME
```

But, looks like, it is not working. Getting this error:

```
main.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'
main.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'
main.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: check it in https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; your own scripts should use lower-case names for variables they define themselves. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities* -- and note that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yup missed the escape on the 2nd one. This question doesn't really warrant an answer. It is pretty well explained in the dupe